# How do I link directly to a comment?

Tags: support

A comment I read on one of my questions has me interested in asking a separate question and I would like to create a link that goes directly to the comment on the question rather than to the top of the question page. I'm sure I've seen it used before and I've looked in the help section but I just can't seem to find the instructions.

Comment: Click on the time and copy the link in the URL bar, to the right of the name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silly me, I guess I should write an answer for this.

If you click on the time since posted next to the user's name:

> Click on the time and copy the link in the URL bar, to the right of the name. –  Compass **1 min ago**

It will give you a link in the URL bar. Or right click and copy URL.

URL for my comment above is: `https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1438/how-do-i-link-directly-to-a-comment#comment5884_1438`

Then, [standard linking](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1438/how-do-i-link-directly-to-a-comment#comment5884_1438) gives you a comment link.

Caveat - modern browsers may only allow the link to work once if the comment is on the same page. Additional clicks will result in the "You're already here" and not refresh the page for you.